# How can I avoid duplicate background task processing in Service Fabric hosted services?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric, ihostedservice

Sorry about the vague title, it's rather hard to explain. I have the following setup:

- I'm running a .NET Core 2.2 Web API hosted in Service Fabric.
- Part of this API's responsibilities is to monitor an external FTP storage for new incoming files.
- Each file will trigger a Mediator `Command` to be invoked with processing logic.
- I've implemented a hybrid solution based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice and https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html. In essence this is an `IHostedService` implementation that is registered in the `Startup.cs` of this API. Its basically a background service running in-process.

As for the problem. The solution above works fine on a 1-node cluster, but causes "duplicates" to be processed when running on a 5-node cluster. The problem lies in the fact that on a 5-node cluster, there are ofcourse 5 identical `ScheduledTasks` running and will all access the *same* file on the FTP at the *same* time.

I've realised this is caused somewhat by improper separation of concerns - aka the API shouldn't be responsible for this, rather a completely separate process should handle this.

This brings me to the different services supported on Service fabric (Stateful, Stateless, Actors and Hosted Guest Exe's). The `Actor` seems to be the only one that runs single-threaded, even on a 5-node cluster. Additionally, an `Actor` doesn't seem to be well suited for this kind of scenario, as it needs to be triggered. In my case, I basically need a daemon that runs all the time on a schedule. If I'm not mistaken, the other stateful/stateless services will run with 5 "clones" as well and just cause the same issue as I currently have.

I guess my question is: how can I do efficient background processing with **Service Fabric** and avoid these multi-threaded/duplicate issues? Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In service farbic you have 2 options with actors:

- [Reliable actor timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders#actor-timers)
- [Reliable actor reminders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders#actor-reminders)

You can use the state to determine if the actor has processed your ftp file.

Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.codit.eu/blog/how-to-enable-automatic-scheduling-in-service-fabric-actors/), to see how they used a reminder to run every 30 seconds.

It's important that the code in your actor allows [reantrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).
Basically because the actors are reliable, your code might get executed multiple times and be canceled in the middle of an execution.

Instead of doing this:

```
public void Method()
{
    _ftpService.Process(file);
}
```

Consider doing this:

```
public void Method(int fileId)
{
    if (_ftpService.IsNotProcessed(fileId))
    {
        _ftpService.Process(file);
        _ftpService.SetProcessed(fileId);
    }
}
```

If your actor has trouble disposing, you might want to check if you are handling cancelationtokens in your code. I never had this issue, but we are using autofac, with [Autofac.ServiceFabric](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/servicefabric.html) to register our actors with `RegisterActor<T>()` and we have cancelationtokens in most of our logic. Also the documentation of [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-3.1#examples) can help you.
Example

```
public Ctor()
{
    _cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _cancellationToken= _cancelationTokenSource.Token;
}

public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    while(/*condition*/)
    {
       _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       /*Other code*/
    }
}

protected override async Task OnDeactivateAsync()
{
    _cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Hi Preben, I have a POC based on the article you linked, but the Actor sometimes has trouble disposing itself and gets "stuck", at which point I have to delete the service and reboot the node... Also, can you elaborate on the 'reantrancy' part please?

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at this!